# What are triangles?

Tags: geometry, definition

I am working on 7.3 in Hartshorne's *Euclid and Beyond* which states:

> Given a triangle $ABC$, show that the sies $\overline{AB}$, $\overline{AC}$, and $\overline{BC}$ and the vertices $A$, $B$, $C$ uniquely determined by the triangle. *Hint:* Consider the different ways in which a line can intersect the triangle.

I would have thought that a triangle was simply $3$ non-colinear points and that all you need to determine the triangle is, well, $A$, $B$, and $C$ (which are unique by assumption) and that any two points determine a unqiue line segment, but I am unsure of this argument since it doesn't use the hint.

I have been trying to find his definition of "triangle", I also looked at [Euclid's elements definitions](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/bookI.html) and could only find 3 definitions about classes of triangles. Also, the idea of angle is covered two sections later as well.

I don't know how to approach this question, because I don't understand what Hartshorne is referring to by a triangle. What definition should I be using?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032258/what-are-triangles-quadrilaterals-etc) appears similar but is more "real world", and less concerned with axiomatic methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hartshorne defines "triangle" in the Definition on page 74.  A triangle is a set of points which is a union of three line segments formed by three noncollinear points.  So, a triangle is the union of its sides, considered as a set of points.

Comment: Ah geez, I probably missed it because it was under "Definition" (no s) and the first thing they mentioned were "line segement". Thanks.